# How much HP does Master Core have?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

When you play on a certain difficulty, you'll face off against a bunch of shadow swords, a shadow dog monster thing and a shadow clone of yourself. But there is no HP count of these guys.

How much HP do they have and does it depend on the difficulty?

Comment: It almost certainly depends on difficulty; it's just incredibly difficult to test, especially because it doesn't appear on all difficulties.

Comment: It always appears on 9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're talking about Master Core.

I can't find anything on either wiki ([1](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Core), [2](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Master_Core)) about how much health it has but [one page](http://www.primagames.com/games/super-smash-bros-wii-u3ds/tips/super-smash-bros-3ds-classic-mode-tips) describes how the health is indicated by how much of the swarm is present which is dependent on difficulty:

> Master Core is surrounded by a swarm-like substance that must be
>   removed. This substance is essentially Master Core's health. The
>   higher the intensity (difficulty) the more dense the substance, and
>   the more health Master Core has.

Comment: Those pages indicate that it doesn't have HP. You can only kill it by KO.